# ASP.NET Core как реализовать сервис, обновляющий данные каждые 3 секунды?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Имеется список подразделений организации. Каждое подразделение имеет уникальное наименование, статус(Активно/Заблокировано). Данные о статусе подразделений отдает сервис А. Статус каждого подразделения должен изменяться каждые 3 секунды. Я пытаюсь реализовать сервис с использованием службы System.Threading.Timer. Проблема в том, что делегат Timer не позволяет возвращать значение(только void), как мне правильно реализовать передачу данных в таком случае?

Comment: что и куда вы возвращать то собрались?

Comment: Наверное, тут лучше какой-то шедулер припахать. Но так то вы можете просто запустить `Thread` и в нём самом делать обновление, а потом спать через `Sleep` до следующего нужного отсчёта времени.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понял, вам нужен постоянно работающий сервис. Или, во всяком случае, долго работающий.

В ASP.NET это реализуется с помощью hosted services.
[Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). Пример кода как раз использует таймер.

---

Как я понял, вы хотите посылать сообщения с сервера на клиент.
Используйте для этого технологию [SignalR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0).
Благодаря веб-сокетам сервер может сам посылать сообщения. Клиентам нет нужды делать постоянный опрос (polling).